# How to change the selected option of a select by using JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html, select

I've got a very simple problem but I can't figure out how to do this ...
In my HTML page, I have a simple select tag :

```
<select id="selection-type">
     <option disabled="disabled">Type</option>
     <option value="0">Tous les types</option>
     <option value="1">Appartement</option> 
     <option value="2">Maison</option>
     <option value="3">Terrain</option>
</select>
```

I want to set a specific value dynamically using JavaScript, but I just managed to change the selected index, and not the displayed value. Currently, I'm doing this (in the footer section of my HTML page) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("selection-type").selectedIndex = 2;
});
</script>
```

And in the result, it's change the selected index of my select, but the displayed text is not "update" : the value "Tous les types" stays. In fact, I want to change the whole selection, e.g. the selected option and not just the index.

Comment: If youre using jquery youre obviously using javascript already, there is no need to edit the tag and add it.(this is a note to the other editor)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using jQuery.  You could use jQuery's `val` method to change the select box, using the `value` of the option you want to select:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selection-type').val('1');
});
```

Or do you need it to be done in plain JavaScript?

**Edit:**

What browser are you using?  The `selectedIndex` thing you're doing actually does work for me in Chrome 24.0.1312.5.

Comment: I tried the first solution, and it doesn't work. I'm using firefox for the tests, but my webiste will be a mobile website, so it will be great if it works on Safari. The method with the selectedIndex just change the selected index, and does not change the value that appears in the select when it's unfold.

Comment: Ok, so are you wanting to change the text of a particular option, rather than the select box's selected option?  For example, change the text "Appartement" to something else?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
document.getElementById("selection-type").value = document.getElementById("selection-type").selectedIndex.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've find a way to make it work. I still use my first method, but i execute it before $(document).ready :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("selection-type").selectedIndex = 2;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ...
     });
</script>
```

I don't understand exactly why .. but it's work. Thanks a lot.